# Soft deletes with slick

Tags: scala, slick

It's possible that this question has been answered before, but I have not found it via search engine or this site's search.

I'm trying to implement soft deletes in my DAO object. My table has a column, `deleted_at`, which is either null or a timestamp. If it's a timestamp it has been soft deleted.

I'm trying to write the query that will perform the soft delete, and this is what I came up with (note that it doesn't work):

```
val suppliers = TableQuery[SuppliersTable]

def softDelete(id: UUID) = {
  suppliers.filter(_.id === id)
    .map(s => (s.deletedAt))
    .update((new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis)))
}
```

The error I get is `Type mistmatch, expected: Option[Timestamp], actual: Timestamp`, which I suspect is for the update, why isn't this valid, and what's the correct version of what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You do not post the table definition but I assume that is Option[Timestamp] if is the case you need to do: Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis))

Comment: Thanks. `Some()` does the trick. I did miss posting the table definition, no wonder I couldn't get an answer

Comment: The error told that: Type mistmatch, expected: Option[Timestamp], actual: Timestamp